# How to call a function inside a callback function

Tags: reactjs

I am having a callback function that triggers handleCartOpen() function. But when the function is triggered I get an error showing 'setDrawerView and openDrawer is not a function

I am having a callback function that triggers handleCartOpen() function. But when the function is triggered I get an error showing 'setDrawerView and openDrawer is not a function

```
 const { openDrawer, setDrawerView } = useUI();

  function handleCartOpen() {
      setDrawerView('CART_SIDEBAR');
      return openDrawer();
    }

 const openCart = useCallback(() => {
      alanInstance.playText("Opening cart")
      handleCartOpen()
  }, [alanInstance, handleCartOpen])
```

useUI Code

```
   const initialState = {
  isAuthorized: getToken() ? true : false,
  displaySidebar: false,
  displayFilter: false,
  displayCart: false,
  displaySearch: false,
  displayMobileSearch: false,
  displayDrawer: false,
  drawerView: null,
  toastText: '',
  isStickyheader: false,
  data: null,
};

type Action =
 
      type: 'OPEN_SIDEBAR';
    }
  | {
      type: 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR';
    }

  | {
      type: 'OPEN_CART';
    }
  | {
      type: 'CLOSE_CART';
    }
  | {
      type: 'OPEN_DRAWER';
      data: null;
    }
  | {
      type: 'CLOSE_DRAWER';
    }
  | {
      type: 'SET_DRAWER_VIEW';
      view: DRAWER_VIEWS;
    };

type DRAWER_VIEWS = 'CART_SIDEBAR' | 'MOBILE_MENU' | 'ORDER_DETAILS';

export const UIContext = React.createContext<State | any>(initialState);

UIContext.displayName = 'UIContext';

function uiReducer(state: State, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'OPEN_SIDEBAR': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displaySidebar: true,
      };
    }
    case 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displaySidebar: false,
        drawerView: null,
      };
    }
    case 'OPEN_SHOP': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displayShop: true,
      };
    }
    case 'OPEN_CART': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displayCart: true,
      };
    }
    case 'CLOSE_CART': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displayCart: false,
      };
    }
    case 'OPEN_DRAWER': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displayDrawer: true,
        displaySidebar: false,
        data: action.data,
      };
    }
    case 'CLOSE_DRAWER': {
      return {
        ...state,
        displayDrawer: false,
      };
    }
    case 'SET_DRAWER_VIEW': {
      return {
        ...state,
        drawerView: action.view,
      };
    }
  }
}

export const UIProvider: React.FC = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(uiReducer, initialState);

  const openSidebar = () => dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_SIDEBAR' });
  const closeSidebar = () => dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR' });
  const toggleSidebar = () =>
    state.displaySidebar
      ? dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_SIDEBAR' })
      : dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_SIDEBAR' });
  const closeSidebarIfPresent = () =>
    state.displaySidebar && dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_CART' });
  const openCart = () => dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_CART' });
  const closeCart = () => dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_CART' });
  const toggleCart = () =>
    state.displaySidebar
      ? dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_CART' })
      : dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_CART' });
  const closeCartIfPresent = () =>
    state.displaySidebar && dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_CART' });

 
  const toggleMobileSearch = () =>
    state.displayMobileSearch
      ? dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_MOBILE_SEARCH' })
      : dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_MOBILE_SEARCH' });
  const openDrawer = (data?: any) => dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_DRAWER', data });
  const closeDrawer = () => dispatch({ type: 'CLOSE_DRAWER' });

 
  const setDrawerView = (view: DRAWER_VIEWS) =>
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_DRAWER_VIEW', view });
  const enableStickyHeader = () => dispatch({ type: 'ENABLE_STICKY_HEADER' });
  const disableStickyHeader = () => dispatch({ type: 'DISABLE_STICKY_HEADER' });

  const value = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...state,
      openSidebar,
      closeSidebar,
      openCart,
      closeCart,
      toggleCart,
      openDrawer,
      closeDrawer,
      setDrawerView,
      enableStickyHeader,
      disableStickyHeader,
    }),
    [state]
  );
  return <UIContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
};

export const useUI = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(UIContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useUI must be used within a UIProvider`);
  }
  return context;
};

export const ManagedUIContext: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <CartProvider>
    <UIProvider>
      <ModalProvider>{children}</ModalProvider>
    </UIProvider>
  </CartProvider>
);
```

I cut out some code that are not important to this question to make the code in useUI short

Comment: What is useUI ? You sure you shouldn't use bracket rather than curly braces there ?

Comment: can you attach useUI code?. i want to view `openDrawer, setDrawerView` function

Comment: @Ivo
 Am sorry for not putting the useUi code initially, kindly re-check i have updated the question with the code

Comment: @Lee  Kindly re-check I have updated the question with the useUi code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`openDrawer` and `setDrawerView` should be:

```js
const openDrawer = (data?: any) => {
   dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_DRAWER', data })
}
const setDrawerView = (view: DRAWER_VIEWS) => {
   dispatch({ type: 'SET_DRAWER_VIEW', view })
}
```

Comment: It's still the same I code as before, though I still used yours and still same error 'TypeError: setDrawerView and openDrawer is not a function'

Comment: can you `console.log(openDrawer, setDrawerView)` and see log?

Comment: This is what I get in the console.  undefined undefined

Comment: can you try move `openDrawer ` `setDrawerView ` to outside function and `export const openDrawer ..` and import to you main code?

Comment: Still undefined undefined